# std::vector<bool>::emplace in C++11

Tags: c++11

According to [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace):

> **Notes**
>
> The specialization `std::vector<bool>` did not have `emplace()` member
>   until C++14.

What does it mean? Can template specialization omit member? Does mean that member function is not present at all? Or is it just not specialized?

Following code seems to work on gcc 7.1.0:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v;
    v.emplace_back(true);
    v.emplace_back(false);
    for (const auto &b : v) {
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }
}
```

http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07c8c0fc6050968f

Comment: You are asking about `emplace` and in code you have `emplace_back`. But `emplace_back` was also added in C++14.

Comment: @Zereges you're right, but both functions have the same note.

Answer (score 3):

A template specialization can be completely different from the generic template. So in theory, you cannot know whether the classes `A<int>` and `A<bool>` have any common members:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    void foo()
    {}
};


template <>
class A<bool>
{
public:
    void bar()
    {}
};


int main()
{
    A<int> a;
    a.foo();

    A<bool> b;
    b.bar();

    b.foo();  // error: 'class A<bool>' has no member named 'foo'
}
```

The class `std::vector<bool>` is a specialized template. Your quote from the standard says that the `emplace()` method was missing in that specialization until C++14.

In practice, concrete standard libraries such as libstdc++ may have provided the `emplace()` method for `std::vector<bool>` even before C++14, but it was not required in the standard.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I was under impression that there's some kind of "inheritance" when specializing a template.