# How to force g++ to compile c++11 standard only?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++

`std::vector<bool>::emplace_back` is [available](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back#Notes) only since C++14. However, with my g++ 5.4.0 it compiles ok even if I specify `-std=c++11`.

When I compile the same code with g++ 4.8.4, it fails. Is there a way how to convince g++ to strictly check the selected standard?

Note: I already use `-pedantic -Wextra -Wall`.

Example `test.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> v;
    v.emplace_back(true);
    return 0;
}
```

Compile with `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test`. With g++ 5.4.0 compiles ok, g++ 4.8.4 fires:

```
test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cpp:6:7: error: ‘class std::vector<bool>’ has no member named ‘emplace_back’
    v.emplace_back(true);
      ^
```

Comment: Absence of `vector<bool>::emplace_back` is not a constraint on conforming *implementations*. It is a constraint on conforming *programs*. An implementation may define additional members in standard classes as it sees fit.

Comment: related (same observation) : [std::vector<bool>::emplace in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44971360/stdvectorboolemplace-in-c11)

Comment: @n.m. where does the standard say implementations may include additional members?

Comment: @hyde: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1zdKHR) with OP's code (after edit).

Comment: gcc 4.8 predates C++14 and doesn't even support all of C++11. It's no wonder it doesn't provide `emplace_back()`. For newer versions, if you don't want to use C++14 library features, don't write code that uses them.

Comment: @Ayxan In the C++11 Stadnard, it's also in the footnote 188: _An implementation
may also define additional member functions that would otherwise not be called by a valid C++ program._

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is related to `libstdc++` that ships with `gcc`. In `libstdc++`, `bits/vector.tcc`, you have the `std::vector<bool>` specialization with

> ```
> #if __cplusplus >= 201103L
> template<typename _Tp, typename _Alloc>
> template<typename... _Args>
> // ... more stuff
> vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::emplace_back(_Args&&... __args)
> ```

The preprocessor branch enables the member function for C++11. In `libc++` (the standard library implementation within the Llvm project), it's different:

> ```
> #if _LIBCPP_STD_VER > 11
> template <class... _Args>
> #if _LIBCPP_STD_VER > 14
> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY reference emplace_back(_Args&&... __args)
> #else
> _LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY void      emplace_back(_Args&&... __args)
> #endif
> ```

so here, `emplace_back` is only defined with a standard beyond C++11. You cannot do much about it, but I see two options.

1. To achieve strict conformance to C++11, not only compile with `g++`, but also with `clang++`. `clang` uses `libc++` by default on MacOS, and on Linux you can pass some flag to enforce that (otherwise, it uses `libstdc++`), which does complain about `emplace_back` with `-std=c++11`. Then use the results of compiling with `clang` to adjust your sources that are otherwise built with `gcc`.
2. Compile with `gcc`, but tell the compiler to use `libcxx`. From [here](https://libcxx.llvm.org/docs/UsingLibcxx.html#id5), this also complains:

   ```
   g++ -std=c++11 -nostdinc++ -I /path/to/libcxx/include -nodefaultlibs \
       -lc++ -lc++abi -lm -lc -lgcc vecbool-emplace_back.cpp
   ```

I would go with option 1, because it hardens your program in different ways, too, not only standard compliance. Also, option 2 is cumbersome.

Comment: This. No compiler is 100% conforming. If you want to harden your code against non-portable behavior like this, you should build with multiple compilers.

Comment: Clang doesn't always use libc++, you may need to ask for it (`-stdlib=libc++`). Here is uses libstdc++ by default.

Comment: Actually we compile with g++, MinGW and MSVC. We also considered clang, but there was no time to setup an automated build yet.

Comment: Who is responsible for libstdc++ and who for libc++? libstdc++ is "part" of g++? And where the libc++ comes from?

Comment: @Mi-La GNU project for libstdc++, LLVM project for libc++.

Comment: Yes, `libstdc++` is "part of `gcc`" in that it ships with `g++` and is tightly coupled to this compiler. I think the lead maintainer/developer is Jonathan Wakely, who is also active on SO. `libc++` is part of the Llvm project. Names that come to my mind w.r.t. `libc++` are Marshall Clow and Howard Hinnant (again, both on SO). But that's just the prominent individuals, I guess you will find many more names involved when you look at the VCS logs.